# Drawing Arc with fill with HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to draw with HTML and CSS:

[image]

I'm trying to drawn an arc with fill inside it, I've tried using border radius, here's [how far I could come](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/kzgdye22/) .

HTML Code:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.box {
   width:500px; height:100px;  
   border:solid 5px #f9955e;
   border-color:#f9955e transparent transparent transparent;
   border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
.box{
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;  
    border-radius: 50% / 100px 0 0 0;
}

.box::before{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#f9955e;
    content:"";
}
```

It doesn't require any change to your html or have the need for a wrapping div. It's just pure CSS.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h2or0xa1/

---

Ok, so here's the explanation:

I got rid of your borders, we're not using those any more.
I've set the `.box` div to have a border radius that creates an arc on the left hand side (assume you know what this is as it's in your example). Set the background of the `.box` div to white.
Added a `::before` pseudo element which essentially creates a div "over the top of" the `.box` div. To move it behind the div I positioned it absolutely and gave it a z-index of -1 which pushes is behind the `.box` div. The background colour of this `::before` pseudo element is the orange you provided. Essentially the `::before` pseudo element creates a div the same size as box, colours it, and pushes is behind `.box`

Comment: Try adding some explanation instead of just passing along working CSS

Comment: Explanation added @TomKriek

Answer (score 1):

You can create the arc using a combination of square and circle overlapping it. The combination can be hidden within a container of half the width and half the height of the square/circle.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpot7yy/)

```css
.container {
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px;
}
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```